# How to useState for each object in an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am new to React and I'm stuck on how to useState correctly. I have a list of objects in an array which I render on the page. Now I need to update properties of individual objects inside the array but the changes are not reflected on the rendered components and I don't know how to setup useState in such a case.

This is what I have so far. I tried to only show the code that is involved. The app should allow to select files via a file input, upload each file to a server and show a progress bar for each file while it uploads.

```js
function MultiFileUpload() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  function onChangeInputFile({ target: { files } }) {
    [...files].forEach((file) => {
      setFiles([...files], file);
      uploadFile(file);
    });
  }

  function uploadFile(file) {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);

    const options = {
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        // This change is not reflected in the component for that file
        file.uploadProgress = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
      },
    };

    axios
      .post(`${apiUrl}/files`, data, options)
      .then((res) => {
        // This change is not reflected in the component for that file
        file.uploadFinished = true;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // This change is not reflected in the component for that file
        file.uploadErrors = err;
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" multiple onChange={onChangeInputFile} />

      {files.map((file, index) => (
        <File key={index} file={file} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function File({ file }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {file.name}
      <ProgressBar now={file.uploadProgress} striped={true} label={`${file.uploadProgress}%`} />
      {file.uploadFinished && <div>Finished!</div>}
      {file.uploadErrors && <div>Failed!</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I setup the state that when I update `files[0].uploadProgress` for example the component for that file rerenders and shows the new value.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. After updating object properties you have to call `setFiles` again like this `setFiles((files) => [...files])`. I don't know if this is the best way tho since it will trigger a rerender of all file components. I also fixed a wrong use of `setFiles` in the `onChangeInputFile` handler.

Here is the updated code:

```js
function MultiFileUpload() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  function onChangeInputFile({ target: { files } }) {
    [...files].forEach((file) => {
      uploadFile(file);
      setFiles((files) => [...files, file])
    });
  }

  function uploadFile(file) {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);

    const options = {
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        file.uploadProgress = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
        setFiles((files) => [...files]);
      },
    };

    axios
      .post(`${apiUrl}/files`, data, options)
      .then((res) => {
        // This change is not reflected in the component for that file
        file.uploadFinished = true;
        setFiles((files) => [...files]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // This change is not reflected in the component for that file
        file.uploadErrors = err;
        setFiles((files) => [...files]);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" multiple onChange={onChangeInputFile} />

      {files.map((file, index) => (
        <File key={index} file={file} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function File({ file }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {file.name}
      <ProgressBar now={file.uploadProgress} striped={true} label={`${file.uploadProgress}%`} />
      {file.uploadFinished && <div>Finished!</div>}
      {file.uploadErrors && <div>Failed!</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use an array in useState or, preferably, the useReducer hook.  More info here: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-usereducer/.

Comment: My question is, how do I update files[0].uploadProgress for example and have the component for that file rerender with the new value.